# there's no error message but this doesn't output anything

Tags: python, class, pygame

don't ask me what i was trying to make here but yall pls help if i just draw a rectangle without the class it works fine but it doesn't output anything, there's not even an error message. should i just not do the class then? i'm terrible at this kind of stuff it tells me i need to write more words and that my post is mostly code so just ignore this stuff rn

```
import pygame
import os
pygame.init()
 
FPS=60

SCREEN = pygame.display.set_mode((400,500))
pygame.display.set_caption('test')

  
x=50
y=450
vel = 3
width = 20
height = 20
walk = pygame.draw.rect(SCREEN, (0,0,0),(x,y,width,height))
class player(object):
    def __init__(self,x,y,width,height):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.vel = 3
    def draw(self,SCREEN):
        SCREEN.blit (walk, (self.x,self.y))
        
    def rdw():
        SCREEN.blit((0,0))
        player.draw(SCREEN)
        pygame.display.update()

player = player(x,y,width,height)
#main loop
running = True
clock = pygame.time.Clock()


while running:
    clock.tick(FPS)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

        
        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    if keys[pygame.K_a] and player.x > 30 - player.width - player.vel:
                x-=player.vel
    if keys[pygame.K_d] and player.x < 400 - player.width - player.vel:
                x+=player.vel



    SCREEN.fill((255, 255, 255))
pygame.display.update()

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: Can you show us the version that does work so we can contrast it with the version that doesn't?

Comment: You never call `player.rdw()` or `player.draw()`. And what is `self.walk` supposed to do?

Comment: Don't use the same name `player` for the class and the variable. Conventionally, class names begin with capital letters.

Comment: Do you think there is a missing indentation in the `pygame.display.update()` code ? I mean, put it inside the while loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a [`pygame.Surface`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html) object size of the player and [`fill`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.fill) it with the color of the player. This is the object you need to [`blit`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.blit) in `Player.draw`:

```py
class Player(object):
    def __init__(self,x,y,width,height):
        # [...]
        
        self.image = pygame.Surface((width, height))
        self.image.fill((0,0,0))
    
    def draw(self,SCREEN):
        SCREEN.blit(self.image, (self.x,self.y))

player = Player(x, y, width, height)
```

When you move the player, you need to change the coordinates of the `player` (`player.x`, `player.y`) instead of `x` and `y`:

```py
keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
if keys[pygame.K_a] and player.x > 30 - player.width - player.vel:
    player.x -= player.vel
if keys[pygame.K_d] and player.x < 400 - player.width - player.vel:
    player.x += player.vel
```

You have to draw the player after clearing the screen and before updating the screen:

```py
SCREEN.fill((255, 255, 255))
player.draw(SCREEN)
pygame.display.update()
```

---

Complete example (care about the [Indentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html)):

```py
import pygame
import os
pygame.init()
 
FPS=60

SCREEN = pygame.display.set_mode((400,500))
pygame.display.set_caption('test')

x=50
y=450
vel = 3
width = 20
height = 20

class Player(object):
    def __init__(self,x,y,width,height):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.vel = 3
        self.image = pygame.Surface((width, height))
        self.image.fill((0,0,0))
    def draw(self,SCREEN):
        SCREEN.blit(self.image, (self.x,self.y))

player = Player(x,y,width,height)

#main loop
running = True
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
while running:
    clock.tick(FPS)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
 
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keys[pygame.K_a] and player.x > 30 - player.width - player.vel:
        player.x -= player.vel
    if keys[pygame.K_d] and player.x < 400 - player.width - player.vel:
        player.x += player.vel

    SCREEN.fill((255, 255, 255))
    player.draw(SCREEN)
    pygame.display.update()

pygame.quit()
```

---

The typical PyGame application loop has to:

- handle the events by either [`pygame.event.pump()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.pump) or [`pygame.event.get()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.get).
- update the game states and positions of objects dependent on the input events and time (respectively frames)
- clear the entire display or draw the background
- draw the entire scene (`blit` all the objects)
- update the display by either [`pygame.display.update()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.update) or [`pygame.display.flip()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.flip)
- limit frames per second to limit CPU usage

Answer (score 0):

`pygame.display.update()` needs to be indented to be inside the `while running` loop.  Also you need to call the player.draw method after filling the screen.

Also, `SCREEN.blit((0,0))` will crash the program as you are not providing it with anything to blit.